# Pony language on Windows with VS2017 or VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017, ponylang

I am looking for a complete instruction on how to setup Pony and make VS2017 or VSCode recognize its syntax, compile and debug program.

So far I've found a plugin for VS2015 (https://github.com/ponylang/VS-pony); however I cannot build the project (project is of course being converted to VS2017 format by VS2017 itself). I've also found some syntax colorizer for VSCode; however I have no clue how to configure building pipe, not mentioning the debugging environment.

Ps. On YouTube there is a lecture on Pony and guys there seem to use VSCode (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vq1vRfv-A6g).
How did they do that? Does any one know?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the plugin only supports syntax highlighting. I haven’t used it myself, but if you go to the Pony mailing list you might be able to find someone who has more information. I believe Sylvan is using Sublime Text in the video you linked to.

Comment: Thank you. I wish Pony were usable with VS2017 though :)